# Hadoop ls command returns null

Tags: hadoop

When I am executing this shell command, it gives me 1st file as null.
I am storing its output in an array,so in array my 1st element is null.
Why it is so?

`hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/ | sort | awk  '{ if (index($8, ".hive") == 0 && $6 $7 <= "'"2016-02-10 05:00"'") print $8 }'`

Comment: I am not sure this has to do with Hadoop, is the file OK?

Comment: File OK means what ? @gsamaras

Comment: I mean that if you would open the file not in the HDFS (for example) would you get the result you expect?

Comment: I am using it in a python script...not sure about local .

Comment: @gsamaras
I have executed : hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/ I am getting "Found 229 items" But when I am executing the whole command I am not getting this 'Found XYZ items'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we do `hadoop fs -ls`, the first line which we get on console is something like,

> Found 10 items

Are you sure that you are not processing this line also? Because, it could result in null element.

If possible, could you please provide output of command `hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/` for reference?

EDIT:

Try this:

`hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/ | grep -v "^Found" | sort | awk  '{ if (index($8, ".hive") == 0 && $6 $7 <= "'"2016-02-10 05:00"'") print $8 }'`

Comment: I mean output of **JUST** this command:

`hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/`

Comment: there is a newline character between command and output files. @daemon12

Comment: I have executed :
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/
I am getting "Found 229 items"
But when I am executing the whole command I am not getting this 'Found XYZ items'

Comment: Can you please explain this issue..why this is happening ?

Comment: I tried your command and for me also it is giving one blank line i.e. null. As I pointed out earlier, it is coming from line similar to "Found 10 items" in your output of `hdfs dfs -ls` command. It's happening because you are printing `$8` which is not present in "Found 10 items" line.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please have a look and check if it works for you.

Comment: Sometime I m receiving "Found 10 items" for he same command and sometime I m not receiving it, is there any issue with sort. Why there is difference in behaviour.